# ScrollView won't scroll, just cuts off the screen. How to fix?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I know this question has been asked, but I haven't found anything that works. Here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.project.myproject.SpendFragment">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/testBannerAdId">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"
        android:padding="@dimen/layoutPadding"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/alabamaButton"
                    android:contentDescription="Alabama"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/alaskaButton"
                    android:contentDescription="Alaska"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/arizonaButton"
                    android:contentDescription="Arizona"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/arkansasButton"
                    android:contentDescription="Arkansas"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/californiaButton"
                    android:text="California"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder2"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/coloradoButton"
                    android:text="Colorado"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder2"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/connecticutButton"
                    android:text="Connecticut"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder2"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/delawareButton"
                    android:text="Delaware"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder2"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/floridaButton"
                    android:text="Florida"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/georgiaButton"
                    android:text="Georgia"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/hawaiiButton"
                    android:text="Hawaii"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/idahoButton"
                    android:text="Idaho"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/illinoisButton"
                    android:text="Illinois"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder2"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/indianaButton"
                    android:text="Indiana"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder2"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/iowaButton"
                    android:text="Iowa"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder2"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/kansasButton"
                    android:text="Kansas"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder2"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/kentuckyButton"
                    android:text="Kentucky"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/louisianaButton"
                    android:text="Louisiana"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/maineButton"
                    android:text="Maine"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/marylandButton"
                    android:text="Maryland"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/massachusettsButton"
                    android:text="Massachusetts"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder2"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/michiganButton"
                    android:text="Michigan"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder2"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/minnesotaButton"
                    android:text="Minnesota"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder2"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/mississippiButton"
                    android:text="Mississippi"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder2"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/missouriButton"
                    android:text="Missouri"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/montanaButton"
                    android:text="Montana"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/nebraskaButton"
                    android:text="Nebraska"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/nevadaButton"
                    android:text="Nevada"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In case it's relevant, here's the xml for the Main activity that the fragment's in:

```
<android.support.design.internal.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:context="com.project.myproject.MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/drawerWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/drawerHeight"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</android.support.design.internal.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>
```

There are more LinearLayouts within the LinearLayout, but you get the idea (more ImageButtons of states). I can see the little scroll thing on the right once, but it disappears and doesn't come back up. And in case it's relevant, there's space for the AdView on the bottom but it's just white space. I know that happens sometimes with a real ad, so I just figure the little placeholder ad will show up eventually.

As you can see, my `ScrollView`'s height is `match_parent` and my `LinearLayout`'s height is `wrap_content`. I have one child in the `ScrollView`. The `ScrollView` is wrapped in a `RelativeLayout` only because I want the `AdView` to be under the `ScrollView`. Is the issue is that there are multiple children in the outer `LinearLayout`? I've never had any issues with ScrollViews before so this is a little annoying haha.

Thank you!

EDIT: Here are two images. The only difference is that one has the little scrollbar on the side and the other doesn't. It disappears and never reappears on touch or movement. The blue squares are the placeholder images and there are four squares per inner LinearLayout.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try making your root Relative layout height to match parent.

Comment: Can you please post your full xml? Also add an image of current behavior.

Comment: @MohammedJunaid Sorry to report no change in behavior

Comment: @FerdousAhamed Just added the full xml and xml for the Main activity

Comment: Your code is ok. I have tried it in my device and looks fine. i am able to scroll up and down.

Comment: Can you please ensure when scrollbar disappers? "" It disappears and never reappears on touch or movement. "??

Comment: @FerdousAhamed I have a navigation drawer in my Main activity to replace different fragments. As soon as I click to get this fragment, I see the scrollbar for a second or two. I don't see it again until the next time I click in the navigation drawer

Answer (score 0):

width and height of ScrollView cannot both be "match_parent".

You can try change the height of ScrollView to "wrap_content" to see if it's work.

Comment: Same problem still

Comment: ScrollView can still work well if having other child in the outer layout. I cannot see any problem in your xml. Maybe you need to try removing(or replace) of the adview / other views once by once to check which view cause the problem. Or may you post a screen shot of your apps?

Comment: Screenshots posted :) I just tried removing the AdView but I'm seeing no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding bottom margin to `ScrollView` as see if it helps:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: Same issue but with a bottom margin

Comment: I tested your xml on my set up. I see no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code + sign is missing in defining Id android:layout_above please add + sign and try once.
instead of this android:layout_above="@id/adView" go for android:layout_above="@+id/adView"

OR

Put your AdView below of ScrollView

Remove your line from ScrollView android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
and put this line to Adview widget

android:layout_below="@+id/scroll_view"